# wcf service runs on browser and on form app but got an error on .netcore project while adding service reference

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, wsdl

I got an error while I was adding wcf service on .net core project.Service runs on another project and it runs on the projects under same solution I can add the reference but it is not working on another project. I got the error which I added below.Also service returns wsdl when I call from browser.

```
An error occurred while attempting to find services at 'http://127.0.0.1:8291/restrictedzone/mex'. 
There was no endpoint listening at http://127.0.0.1:8291/restrictedzone/mex that could accept the message. 
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. 
See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Comment: What does your innerexception tell you?

Comment: It is empty. I have a problem while adding to core project it works fine with framework project